# How to get Value In a ComboBox WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

The next code is some kind of weird, but I have to modify to get the value of a selection, in the XAML; takes ItemsSource from a property in the view model...
XAML

```
<ComboBox Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ReglaMateABC, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Contribucion.ReglaMatematicaTexto, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
```

in MVVM code:

```
    public List<String> ReglaMateABC
    {
        get
        {
            List<String> data = new List<string>();
            data.Add(ControlesResource.TextoReglaMatematicaAB);
            data.Add(ControlesResource.TextoReglaMatematicaC);   
            data.Add(ControlesResource.TextoReglaMatematicaD);             
            return data;
        }
    // this set is added for me
        set
        {
              **SomeVariable** = value;
              this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ListTipoPpa);
        }

    }
```

the **ControlesResource.TextoReglaMatematicaxx** is Taken from a resource file.

what type of variable (**SomeVariable**) should i use?

Prism.ViewModel is being used, and RaisePropertyChanged what it takes to work?

**UPDATE** this is transfer object class that is binding in the XAML file, in 
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=**Contribucion.ReglaMatematicaTexto** ...

```
    public class ContribucionTO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identificador de la Contribución.
    /// </summary>
    public string ContribucionId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Vigencia de la contribución.
    /// </summary>
    public VigenciaTO Vigencia { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Nombre de la contribución.
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ContribucionTONombreRequerido", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MensajesValidacionResource))]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 0, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ContribucionTONombreLongitud", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MensajesValidacionResource))]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Descripción de la contribución.
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ContribucionTODescripcionRequerido", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MensajesValidacionResource))]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 0, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ContribucionTODescripcionLongituda", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MensajesValidacionResource))]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Valor de la tarifa de la contribución.
    /// </summary>        
    public decimal Tarifa { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indica si la tarifa de la contribución se actualiza o no.
    /// </summary>
    public bool ActualizaTarifa { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indica si la regla matemática a utilizar es A+B (True) o C (False)
    /// </summary>
    public bool ReglaMatematica { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicador base de la contribución.
    /// </summary>
    public IndicadorTO IndicadorBase { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convocatorias que se excluyen de la distribución de la contribución.
    /// </summary>
    public List<ConvocatoriaTO> ConvocatoriasExcluidas { get; set; }

}//end ContribucionTO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the type of variable, you should use a List. But i see that it is pointless to set it as you are calculating and returning the list on the get accessor.

As for the selected value, you have the SelectedItem binding in your xaml code, and you should use the Contribucion.ReglaMaticaTexto property.

Edit:
From the discussion in the comments, I understand that you should update your ViewModel class with another property to bind the selection of the ComboBox. You should not bind directly to the Contribucion class.

A suggestion is:

```
private string selectedMathRule; 
public string SelectedMathRule 
{ 
  get { return this.selectedMathRule; } 
  set { SetProperty(ref this.selectedMathRule, value); } 
}
```

Comment: don't get the value of Contribucion.ReglaMaticaTexto

Comment: I do not understand then what you are trying to do. How come you have set that binding?

Comment: I trying to get the value of a selected item

Comment: And by the way it is set up, it's bound to Contribucion.ReglaMaticaTexto. Where is this property defined? Does it have a RaisePropertyChanged on its setter?

Comment: Also, why are you raising the change event for the ListTipoPpa?

Comment: Contribucion is a transfer object class

Comment: But you are not using it as a DTO if you are trying to bind directly to it. By following MVVM pattern, you should have a separate ViewModel class. You could bind it to a property like this: 

private string selectedMathRule;
public string SelectedMathRule
{
    get { return this.selectedMathRule; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref this.selectedMathRule, value);
    }
}

Then, you will have to assign its value to the contribucion dto when you need it

Comment: Thx @Sokopa It works, you must post it as an answer!!

Comment: I updated my original answer. I would appreciate it if you accepted it as an answer to your question